# Why should I use __all__ in __init__ of python package?

Tags: python, package

I've already read [Can someone explain __all__ in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834/can-someone-explain-all-in-python) and I understand that it only affects `from ... import *` statements, but I can't figure out a real use case. Why should I repeat exported names in `__all__` (DRY!) when I could simply avoid importing those names in `__init__` namespace?

Example:

`mypackage/__init__.py`

```
from a import A
```

`mypackage/a.py`

```
A = "A"
A1 = "A1"
```

`mypackage/b.py`

```
B = "B"
```

And then in python:

```
>>> from mypackage import *
>>> A
'A'
>>> 
>>> A1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'A1' is not defined
>>> b
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'b' is not defined
```

As you can see `A` is in the namespace but `A1` and `b` are not. Why should I have to define `__all__ = ["A"]`?

Answer (score 18):

The *only* time you want to define `__all__` in your package's `__init__.py` is to list the names of "exported" members that you want to export for when a user does:

```
from package import *
```

This is documented in [6.4.1. Importing * From a Package](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package)

**Note:** If you *don't* define an `__all__` in your package then the default behaviour is as follows (*from the documentation*):

> If `__all__` is not defined, the statement `from sound.effects import *`
> does not import all submodules from the package sound.effects into the
> current namespace; it only ensures that the package sound.effects has
> been imported (*possibly running any initialization code in
> `__init__.py`*) and then imports whatever names are defined in the package. This includes any names defined (*and submodules explicitly
> loaded*) by `__init__.py`. It also includes any submodules of the package
> that were explicitly loaded by previous import statements. Consider
> this code:

A "naive" interpretation of this can be:

> If you don't define `__all__`; a `from package import *` will bring in everything from that package and anything imported in **that** pacakge's `__init__.py`.

Comment: Look at my example: I didn't use `__all__` but I can show or hide names in `from mypackage import *` anyway. So why using it?

Comment: @Zac you can restrict what comes with `*`. In your example it will bring everything.

Comment: @PeterWood: not everything but only what is imported in `__init__` (updated example in question)

Comment: "If you don't define `__all__`; a `from package import *` will bring in everything from that package and all subpackages." Not everything but only what is imported in `__init__`

Comment: @Zac You may want to initialise the package and need to import identifiers in order to do that. But you may not want to export them with your package. So you can control it using `__all__`.

Comment: it is discouraged to do this: ``Wildcard imports (from <module> import *) should be avoided`` https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/