# Deeply nested namespaced packages

Tags: python, setuptools, packaging

I need to maintain some ETL tool constructed in such a way tasks and pipelines are defined as collection of python packages. Think about plugin architecture with small core and almost thousand of plugins in nested namespaces/packages/subpackages. This is not a hot mess *yet*, overall quality is quite good, but `setup.py` and `__init__.py`-s look very hacky and sometimes cause unexpected problems during imports.

I would like to simplify this a bit. Since Python 3.3 we can put packages in namespaces simply by creating subdirectories without `__init__.py`. This is exactly what I need, but I would like to avoid deeply nested subdirectories in source code, because a large amount of packages is very small. In extreme they would look like this:

```
$ tree
.
├── setup.cfg
├── setup.py
└── src
    └── foo
        └── bar
            └── baz
                └── xyz
                    └── uvw
                        └── package
                            ├── actual_code.py
                            └── __init__.py
```

Is there a way to use implicit namespaces without so deep structure and simply specify namespace somewhere in `setup.py` (or even better `setup.cfg`)? In other words, is there a **simple** way to tell: install `package` in `foo.bar.baz.xyz.uvw` namespace?

I would like to have structure like this:

```
$ tree
.
├── setup.cfg
├── setup.py
└── src
    └── package
        ├── actual_code.py
        └── __init__.py
```

but installation process should put `package` into `foo/bar/baz/xyz/uvw/package` folder, so it could be imported with full path.

Edit: Is this even a good idea?

Comment: Have you looked into specifying `__all__`? [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30888683/why-should-i-use-all-in-init-of-python-package)

Comment: This is not about making long imports short. I need to have that deep structure _after_ installation, but I don't want it in source code repository.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible using the `package_dir` argument to `distutils.core.setup` (or equivalent from `setuptools`).

Just modify your `setup.py` to contain something like:

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(# ... other setup arguments ...
      package_dir={'foo.bar.baz.xyz.uvw': 'src'},
      packages=['foo.bar.baz.xyz.uvw.package'],
     )
```

The key part here is that `package_dir` is saying "the contents of `foo.bar.baz.xyz.uvw` are what is found in the `src` directory", while `packages=['foo.bar.baz.xyz.uvw.package']` tells it to expect to find and install a package named `foo.bar.baz.xyz.uvw.package`.

The `setup.cfg` equivalent would be:

```ini
[options]
package_dir=
    foo.bar.baz.xyz.uvw=src
packages = foo.bar.baz.xyz.uvw.package
```

Comment: FYI, I couldn't find a convenient way of using `setuptools.find_namespace_packages` (or the `setup.cfg` approach of `packages=find_namespace:` directive, with `[option.packages.find]` using the `where` key) to avoid needing to manually list the contents of `packages`, so this does end up a little redundant (`foo.bar.baz.xyz.uvw` has to be typed multiple times). If someone knows how to do this, please chime in; `find_namespace_packages` could be used with a list comprehension to programmatically fix up the prefix, but an existing API that does it for you would be preferable.

Comment: Oh, so this is how it works. This is almost perfect solution, thank you!

Comment: Repetition is not a big problem, because I also wanted to create single template for all packages. It seems to be possible now (and quite simple).